# Non-Hacky Way To Remove ContentInset From UITableView Inside UITabBar with Hidden Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

So, I have a setup as follows:

UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController

The TabBarController has another view, but that's unimportant. I have the TabBar set to hidden because the user should not be doing the switching between views.

I created a demo project to reproduce the issue with exactly as I described above.

[image: Storyboard View]

I called

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Inside the viewDidLoad method of the tableViewController and was, of course, left with this issue:

[image: ContentInset of UITableView in hidden TabBarController][image: tableView plain]

So, how did I end up solving *hacking* my problem?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tableView.contentInset.top, self.tableView.contentInset.left, 0, self.tableView.contentInset.right)];
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tableView.contentInset.top, self.tableView.contentInset.left, 0, self.tableView.contentInset.right)];
}
```

I had to put it inside viewDidAppear because it didn't work in viewDidLoad.

So, does anyone know / can anyone think of a non-hacky way to solve this issue?

Here's a link to the project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a6dxecssl3csds7/AAC7xNhSEuawMWCk6hAvyQVYa?dl=0

Comment: Use table view style plain???

Comment: Did you try? It does the exact same thing. Also, I'm looking to use a grouped tableView, not a plain tableView.

Comment: I tried. If you change the tableview style in the storyboard I dont see any paddings. If you want the grouped tableview behavior with no padding between section headers and the first cell, I don't think it's possible even with some hacky way.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear about my goal. I'm looking to remove the extra padding at the bottom of the tableview (that is only seen in the scroll indicator) that is a result from the missing tabBar.